# Ignore blank cells in a range

Tags: vba, excel

Beginner in VBA here. I'm trying to pull a range of cells into a different workbook and when it does, it pastes blanks as "12:00:00AM." I'm trying to have it copy over exactly, having blanks in the target workbook just as in the source.

**Current code**

```
Sub GetDinServRange()

With Range("A37:E111")
    If Not IsEmpty("A37:E111") Then
        With Range("A37:E111")
            .Formula = "='C:\FILEPATH\FILE'!A37:E111"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: your target cells have DateFormat. Change that . Else change your formula to return "" in case of 0/blank.

Comment: You could paste special for values.  This would drop any formulas/etc which exist in the source workbook.

Comment: try using `If` in the formula, if it's blank then put `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.Formula = "='C:\FILEPATH\FILE'!A37:E111"
```

to

```
.Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK('C:\FILEPATH\FILE'!A37:E111),"""",'C:\FILEPATH\FILE'!A37:E111)"
```

or

```
.Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK('C:\FILEPATH\FILE'!A37:E111)," & CHR(34) & CHR(34) & ",'C:\FILEPATH\FILE'!A37:E111)"
```

Note: Either Double Double Quotes ("""") or CHR(34) are needed in VBA to make Double quotes appear in the actual Excel formula.